# node.js complex distributed job scheduling

Tags: node.js, job-scheduling

I have tried to schedule a simple task with a complex cron expression with no luck with different solutions (cron, agenda...).
Is there a way of executing something like this?

```
Execute task on just on 10-Oct-2014 every minute from 15 to 20 h.
```

I also need it to be persistent, so it should be using some kind of data store.

Comment: you can do this by simply using [`cron`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

Comment: If you use Redis, there is `node-quartz`.

Comment: node-cron does not seem to be persistent and distributed.   
is node-quartz reliable? it seems very new... have you used it?